# Instagram api limit in large, public app

Tags: api, instagram

We've a large open system which offers the possibility to host a large number of apps. Every app has roughly 100 to 500 active users. The backend has the option to add a photo album page and I'd like to add Instagram as a feature. The app admin only has to add the username of his/her instagram account to make the connection. But with this number of apps and end users we reach the api limit with our developer account rather quickly. Is there some sort of workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding the API limit is 5000 requests per hour per **access_token** or **client_id**. Since every user on your system should have their own **access_token**, and as long as the requests from your application uses each individual **access token**, you should be fine since that limit is going to be a per user limit.

Refer to [Instagram End Point > Limits](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/#)

```
You are limited to 5000 requests per hour per access_token or client_id overall. 
Practically, this means you should (when possible) authenticate users so that 
limits are well outside the reach of a given user.
```